# Can not run the `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`, with the log of `no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode`

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have bellow config of `uwsgi.ini`, you can see the bellow config.
I think there is no problem with my configuration but there still can not run uWSGI success.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/data/lll/repo/Qn
uid=nobody
gid=nobody
module=Qn.wsgi:application
socket=/data/lll/repo/Qn/uwsgi.sock
master=true
workers=5
pidfile=/data/lll/repo/Qn/uwsgi.pid
vacuum=true
thunder-lock=true
enable-threads=true
harakiri=30
post-buffering=4096
daemonize=/data/lll/repo/Qn/uwsgi.log
```

then I run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`.
get the bellow traceback in `uwsgi.log`:

```
...
chdir() to /data/lll/repo/Qn
your processes number limit is 4096
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 8192
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /data/lll/repo/Qn/uwsgi.sock fd 3
dropping root privileges after socket binding
dropping root privileges after plugin initialization
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 486672 bytes (475 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
dropping root privileges after application loading
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4004)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4005, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 4006, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 4007, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 4008, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 4009, cores: 1)
```

seems the uWSGI unable to start up.

my `wsgi.py` config is bellow:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Qn.settings")

import django

print("django.setup()")
django.setup()

from socketio import Middleware
from qn_admin_website_chat.views import sio

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import eventlet
    import eventlet.wsgi
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has been around for a while, so I am sure you have found a solution one way or another. But it looks like you are doing `chdir=/data/lll/repo/Qn` and then `module=Qn.wsgi:application`. Did you have a Qn module inside the Qn repo? Is there either `/data/lll/repo/Qn/Qn.py` or `/data/lll/repo/Qn/Qn/__init__.py`?